# Why does Upstart need `setgid` when I have `setuid` and the user is a member of the group?

Tags: 12.04, upstart

I'm attempting to configure Upstart to run a small utility that needs to access a tty as a system-wide daemon. When run from the command-line, the utility remains in the foreground and doesn't exit until a Ctrl+C; I've therefore omitted the `expect` stanza and Upstart is correctly tracking the PID. I've also created an unprivileged account for the daemon using `adduser --system --no-create-home --disabled-login avrlirc`.

On my system, the tty the utility needs to access is installed as:

```
crw-rw----   1 root dialout 166,   0 May 24 19:25 ttyACM0
```

So I added the user `avrlirc` (created above) to the `dialout` group. When I run the utility as `avrlirc` everything works as expected. I added the stanza `setuid avrlirc` to the Upstart configuration file, and the job fails with "can't open tty".

If I omit the `setuid` stanza, it works (so it's likely a permissions thing). If I add the `setgid dialout` stanza alongside the `setuid`, it also works.

So, why do I need `setgid` when I already have `setuid` and the user is a member of the appropriate group—why isn't that enough?

For reference, the Upstart job config file is:

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]
console log
setuid avrlirc
setgid dialout
exec /usr/local/bin/avrlirc2udp -f -H -h <IP_ADDRESS> -t /dev/ttyACM0
```

Where `<IP_ADDRESS>` is the IPv4 address of the local box and within 192.168.0.0/16.

Comment: For completeness (though I don't expect it's particularly relevant), the utility in question is `avrlirc2udp` ([details](http://www.foxharp.boston.ma.us/avrlirc/)), which accepts serial input from an Arduino Uno with IR receiver and sends it on to LIRC via UDP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`setuid` does not set supplementary groups, only primary group. See Upstart bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/upstart/+bug/812870 .

To verify the case, you can check `grep Gid /proc/YOURPID/status` vs `id YOURUSER`.

Comment: Ahh, of course. I'd forgotten that under *nix not all groups are created equal. ;)